# Browser can't open sometime on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

In my app, when user click a button , a url will open on blackberry browser using default browser session.

Some time browser screen can't open. i check other browser application ,its also can not open.

What is the problem...? browser screen is run after restart the device only..

Pls help me.. what is the problem  and how to correct it..

Comment: Post the code that u use to open the url and give us what OS are experiencing this problems...

Comment: In simulator, there is no problem. My device is 9800(os-6) . The problem occur on my device , sometime only.          The Code is :int DEFAULT_BROWSER = 0;
                  browserSession = launchBrowser(DEFAULT_BROWSER, URL);  BrowserSession browserSession = createBrowserSession(browserType);
     browserSession.displayPage(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view the problem is not related to your application. It is related to your BlackBerry device. There is something wrong with the device software and data saved on the device.

Make selective (not full) backup with [BlackBerry Desktop Manager](http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/desktop/). After that [wipe the device memory](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1314) and restore backup file back to the device.